# substr_replace function returns weird symbols along with the string

Tags: php, string, substring

I've a variable with some string in it, for example:

```
$var = "myText";
```

What I want to do is to "inject" before the last word a single quotation mark (`'`) so the output will be:

`myTex't`

I've got this code:

```
$var = "myText";
$var = substr_replace($var, "'", strlen($var)-1, 0);
echo $var;
```

And it works good. The only problem is, when I try to implement it to another language(hebrew in this case) I'm getting additional characters. For instance, for that Input:

`עברית` I'm expecting result of: `עברי'ת` but instead, I'm getting this as a result: `עברי�'�`

Any ideas?

**P.S. Hebrew is Right to Left language**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using multibyte string and substr_replace is not multibyte compatible.

Here is a version that mimics the behavior of substr_replace() exactly: (From [substr_replace](http://php.net/substr_replace) PHP Manual user comment)

```
<?php

if (function_exists('mb_substr_replace') === false)
 {
     function mb_substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start, $length = null, $encoding = null)
     {
         if (extension_loaded('mbstring') === true)
         {
             $string_length = (is_null($encoding) === true) ? mb_strlen($string) : mb_strlen($string, $encoding);

             if ($start < 0)
             {
                 $start = max(0, $string_length + $start);
             }

             else if ($start > $string_length)
             {
                 $start = $string_length;
             }

             if ($length < 0)
             {
                 $length = max(0, $string_length - $start + $length);
             }

             else if ((is_null($length) === true) || ($length > $string_length))
             {
                 $length = $string_length;
             }

             if (($start + $length) > $string_length)
             {
                 $length = $string_length - $start;
             }

             if (is_null($encoding) === true)
             {
                 return mb_substr($string, 0, $start) . $replacement . mb_substr($string, $start + $length, $string_length - $start - $length);
             }

             return mb_substr($string, 0, $start, $encoding) . $replacement . mb_substr($string, $start + $length, $string_length - $start - $length, $encoding);
         }

         return (is_null($length) === true) ? substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start) : substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start, $length);
     }
 }

?>
```

Comment: And what would be the way to use it? just call `substr_replace`?

Comment: call `mb_substr_replace`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are working with unicode multibyte strings. `substr_replace()` works byte wise. So if you are just replacing the last *byte*, it will possibly destroy the last *character* (if this is a multibyte character).

Use can use `preg_replace` instead of `substr_replace()`, it is unicode safe if you pass the `u` option:

```
preg_replace('~(.)$~u', '\'$1', $string);
```

Comment: Use it when? After I'm being returned with the weird output?

Comment: Use it instead of subtring_replace()

Comment: unfortunately, It doesn't work. Same result as the `substr_replace` method